# Identical Factor Variables give different output of the same ordinal logistic regression model

Tags: r, regression, categorical-data

Is there any reason `clm()` (`ordinal` package) function gives different model statistics when IV factors are the same, but once coded as factors from numbers and once from strings?

**Explanation and working example**

Assume following data:

```r
c <- data.frame(a=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0), b=c(1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0), c=c(1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0))
c$dv <- factor(c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,1), ordered=TRUE)
c$factorA <- factor(c$a)
c$factorB <- factor(c$b)
c$factorC <- factor(c$c)
c$factorStringA <- "Human"
c$factorStringA[c$a == 0] <- "Inhuman"
c$factorStringB <- "Lemon"
c$factorStringB[c$b == 0] <- "Orange"
c$factorStringC <- "Plant"
c$factorStringC[c$c == 0] <- "Animal"
c$factorStringA <- factor(c$factorStringA)
c$factorStringB <- factor(c$factorStringB)
c$factorStringC <- factor(c$factorStringC)
```

There are dummy factor variables that were strings at the beginning (i.e. `$factorStringA`) and factor variables that were `num` in the beginning (i.e. `$factorA`). As one can see, each type of variable differentiates the data in the same way (i.e. `$factorA` has the same distribution as the `$factorStringA`).

I ran this ordinal logistic regression in R (with `ordinal` package):

```
clm(dv ~ factorA * factorB, data=c)
```

and I get following results with `summary()`:

```r
 link  threshold nobs logLik AIC   niter max.grad cond.H 
 logit flexible  12   -17.85 57.71 4(0)  4.03e-07 2.3e+02

Coefficients:
                  Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
factorA1             1.898      1.846   1.028    0.304
factorB1             1.348      1.663   0.810    0.418
factorA1:factorB1   -2.933      2.331  -1.259    0.208
```

I ran the same model with corresponding factor variables:

```r
summary(clm(dv ~ factorStringA * factorStringB, data=c))

link  threshold nobs logLik AIC   niter max.grad cond.H 
 logit flexible  12   -17.85 57.71 4(0)  4.03e-07 1.6e+02

Coefficients:
                                         Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
factorStringAInhuman                        1.042      1.323   0.788    0.431
factorStringBOrange                         1.668      1.612   1.035    0.301
factorStringAInhuman:factorStringBOrange   -2.998      2.357  -1.272    0.203
```

The differences are there. First, I thought they might have to do with the order of factors (even though order was not declared for either of them), but that did not help. Second, I thought that calculating interactions were at fault: but simulations of simple `factorA + factorB` and corresponding `factorStringA + factorStringB` models proved that this is not the case.

While in the above example differences are minimal, in my real dataset differences are meaningful (they make some interactions and main effects significant and others not). My data is precisely of this kind: ordinal dependent variable and couple of binary dummy categorical factors.

Do you guys know the reason for why the way IVs are coded (seemingly identical ways tbh) matters?

Comment: Try `levels(your_factor)`. You likely have different categories in the intercept using each method.

Comment: @frans-rodenburg Levels output for `factorA` = `[1] "0" "1"`, for `factorB` = `[1] "0" "1"`. For `factorStringA` = `[1] "Human"   "Inhuman"`, for `factorStringB` = `[1] "Lemon"  "Orange"`. Oh, so if I have factorA values coded as category 1 and 0 then R treats factorB values as coming from the same categories, and that is what influences the results? [checks]  I've checked,even if I switch categories in factorA and factorB to be unique, the clm() still gives different output than when the model is made with factorStringA and factorStringB.